# Identifying date of family prayer book?

Tags: artifacts

I have a slightly vandalised little pocket prayer book (pictured below) titled *Prayers and Promises*. I am trying to identify the original owner. On the inside is written "To Ellen" and "From Eunice", indicating it was likely a gift.

In order to try to trace the owner – or gifter – it would be helpful to know approximately when the book may have been published. I'm not even sure whether the book is from the 19th or 20th century?

It definitely belonged to someone in my grandmother's family, and perhaps was given to a child given some of the indecipherable scribbles.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the next two pages? There appear to be editions from the mid-nineteenth century on.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl From memory the next two pages don't contain anything very useful for identifying the edition. I don't have the book in front of me right now but will get a picture later

Comment: Odd -- that's where I'd expect to see the reprint history.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I can confirm the next page is blank, and then the daily prayers start on the following page. I've looked through the entire book and there is no further information I can see that would be useful for determining date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_Tract_Society):

> The Religious Tract Society, founded 1799, 56 Paternoster Row and 65 St. Paul's Chuchyard and 164 Piccadilly ...

All three addresses<sup>†</sup> were printed at one time, for example [1888](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/The-Heroines-of-Haarlem-Harriette-E-Burch-The-Religious-Tract-Society-1888/142509575394?hash=item212e3b8ce2:g:wTgAAOSwKZ5ZvYK~):

[image]

Two of the above addresses were printed at least until [1899](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/The-Story-of-the-Religious-Tract-Society-for-One-Hundred-Years-Samuel-G-Green/362237946108?hash=item54571068fc:g:oO4AAOSwnlFafw28):

[image: 1899 example]

and one through to at least [1919](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/The-Pilgrims-Progress-John-Bunyan-The-Religious-Tract-Society-1919-TBLO/263508527070?_trkparms=ao%3D1%26asc%3D20170912102017%26meid%3D931e3cca6f264ca4a02cc2957bb7d090%26pid%3D100706%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26%26itm%3D263508527070&_trksid=p2045573.c100706.m4781):

[image: 1919 example]

with `4 Bouverie Street` on its own in use by [1938](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1938-Illustrated-New-Testament-Prize-Award-by-The-Religious-Tract-Society/273123820842?hash=item3f9772c52a:g:rk8AAOSw3fZZ7MZv):

[image: 1938 example]

So 20th Century seems very much more likely than 19th.

Again from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_Tract_Society):

> In 1935 the RTS merged with the Christian Literature Society for India and Africa to form the United Society for Christian Literature (USCL). In 1931, there was a change of imprint to Lutterworth Press for all RTS publications intended for the home market.

So this edition probably reprinted (the first edition seems may have been [1850](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Daily_Prayers_and_Promises_from_the_Holy.html?id=NPy7swEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)) before 1935. Of course the copy you mention was not necessarily acquired "hot off the press".

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Some details of [The Society's Premises](https://archive.org/stream/storyofreligious00reli/storyofreligious00reli_djvu.txt) in its early days:</sub>

> The publishing business of the Religious Tract Society was first
>   carried on at 10,  Stationers' Court, a narrow lane which still runs
>   from Ludgate Hill to Stationers' Hall.  Whence, in 1806, the Society
>   removed to' 60, Paternoster Row. In 1820, premises were  taken at 14,
>   Newgate Street, but, the result not proving satisfactory, Paternoster
>   Row was  tried again ; this time at No. 56. There, for the greater
>   part of the century, has been  the home of the Religious Tract
>   Society. The houses Nos. 57, 58, and 59 were subsequently  added; then
>   65, St. Paul's Churchyard, where the retail Book Saloon, with
>   Committee  Room above, still stands, and, finally, four small houses
>   in Chapter-house Court, occupied  in ancient times by the monks of St.
>   Paul's.

<sub>There *might* be more in a publication such as [A short history of the Religious Tract Society](https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/handle/10023/8124).</sub>

Comment: That "short history" link includes a line: "In 1930, all the Society’s operations were moved under one roof (in its Bouverie
Street premises) ". It puts the Lutterworth rebranding in 1932. If both of those would be reflected in the printing, that leaves a pretty narrow window for the publication of this book. (Unless it was printed for an overseas market, in which case it could post-date 1931/2.)

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the design on the inside title page is after the Art Nouveau style of Charles Rennie Mackintosh, who lived from 1868 to 1928. Mackintosh's designs gained in popularity in the decades following his death, so the design in the book seems to put it its release after 1928, so possibly the 1930's.